# User Control Buttons to Close a Dialog Box

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dialogresult

I have created a User Control in my application that has a textbox and then 2 buttons on it.  One button is to Add data to the DB from the textbox and the second Cancels the action.  This User Control is then added to multiple Dialogs (forms) but I want the buttons to trigger the same events, which the reason I placed the buttons on the User Control and not the Dialog.

What I am trying to do is after they click the Add data button and it is successful, I want it to close the Dialog that the control is located on.

EDIT:

I don't know how to go about coding this to close the Dialog when it is triggered from a User Control. I don't know where to start because I haven't used User Controls before. Typically I just have the controls on a Dialog which allows for the `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion would be for to show us some code and state precisely what you mean by "this is not working". It's hard to tell from here what that means.

Comment: You are correct, that is my fault for not being clear.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. You still do not state the problem.

Comment: Sorry if the edit doesn't help, I don't know how to explain my issue clearly I guess.

Comment: What you should do is tell us more about what isn't working. Is there an error. Is the form simply not closing. If it's the latter then I think I have the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms opened modally will close automatically when their DialogResult is set. From the sounds of it, you are setting the DialogResult of the control, not the form. To do what are you are trying to do, you need the control to set or trigger the setting of the parent forms dialog result.  You can do this by either:

**1.** Passing through a reference of the form to the control, which
    allows the control to set it.

**2.** Create an event on the control that the forms listens to,
    which tells it to close. *(recomemnded way)*

**3.** *(The hacky way)* Set the forms dialog result using this code:

```
this.ParentForm.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

The form will also need to be shown modally, otherwise you will need to call the Close() method manually.

Comment: Did a little research on dialogresult closing a modal dialog, according to the documentation we are wrong on the close part.

Comment: Setting up an event might be a little bit more work but I would also recommend doing it that way. Ultimately, it's the form who should be responsible of closing itself, not a containing control. So an event notifies of the fact that a button has been pressed in the user control, and the form then decides how to react to this event (by closing itself in this case).

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use delegates to solve this problem.

In the code behind of your control, define a delegate which you will use to tell your main form to close itself. Wherever in your control you want to have the parent form close, you will raise this custom event which will be handled by your parent form. For sake of example, we'll assum you want to close the parent form on a button click in the control

```
public delegate void CloseHostFormEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class MyControl : Control {

    public event CloseHostFormEventHandler CloseFormEvent;


    public closeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs) {
        // do your db stuff

        // you could create your own class here and pass the object to your main form if you wanted
        EventArgs myargs = new EventArgs(); 

        // tell host form to close itself
        CloseFormEvent(this, myargs);

    }
}
```

Now in your parent form, you will want to handle the event raised by the control.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form {

    public MyForm() {

        InitializeComponent();

        // ill assume your control was added via the designer and thus done in InitializeComponent()

        // hook up event handler
        mycontrol.CloseFormEvent += CloseFormEventHandler(closeformCallback);
    }

    protected void closeformCallback(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. The accepted answer is correct, but this one tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a wild guess since you haven't given much information.

The dialog doesn't close because it isn't a modal dialog. Try showing it with `ShowDialog()` rather than `Show()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Tony says. You would need to call the close method.

What you could do is pass a reference to the calling from into your control and call its close method from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can put in the Click event handler on your user control something like this:

```
        Form f = this.ParentForm;
        if (f != null)
        {
            f.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

DialogResult does not close a <strike>**non-modal**</strike> form.

You need to call the Close method of the form or in this case dialog.

**EDIT**

Or use ShowDialog() instead of Show().

***EDIT AGAIN***

According to [DialogResult documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx):

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close button (the button with an X in the top-right corner of the form) causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set to DialogResult.Cancel. The Close method is not automatically called when the user clicks the Close button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead, the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because of this behavior, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

Comment: It does if the form was opened modally

Comment: LOL.  Can't believe I forgot that in my answer. :P

Comment: Did a little research on that, according to the documentation we are wrong on the close part.